# How to connect a webpage to a database using PHP and MySQLi in Dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using Dreamweaver to generate PHP and SQLi codes for connecting to a database. This I have done successfully but I keep getting the following errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp\www\Maseno\Site\Template.php on line 32

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp\www\Maseno\Site\Template.php on line 34

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\Maseno\Site\Template.php on line 34,
```

Here is my source code:

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/connect.php'); ?>
<?php

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
  function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", 
                             $theNotDefinedValue = "") {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

    $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?  
      mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

    switch ($theType) {
      case "text":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
        break;    
      case "long":
      case "int":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
        break;
      case "double":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
        break;
      case "date":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
        break;
      case "defined":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
        break;
    }
    return $theValue;
  }
}

mysqli_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
$query_Users = "SELECT * FROM students";
$Users = mysqli_query($query_Users, $connect) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_Users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Users);
$totalRows_Users = mysqli_num_rows($Users);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the part where you connect to the database, but when you connect using [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), the function returns a [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) object (or `false` on failure). If you are using procedural style, then this object must be passed as a parameter to most of your MySQLi functions.

In this code:

> ```
> mysqli_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
> $query_Users = "SELECT * FROM students";
> $Users = mysqli_query($query_Users, $connect) or die(mysqli_error());
> $row_Users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Users);
> $totalRows_Users = mysqli_num_rows($Users);
> ```

the calls to the following functions are incorrect:

- [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
- [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

There is also a problem with your [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) call since PHP is complaining about the first argument being a string. I believe you have the parameters in the wrong order; The order of the parameters to [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) is **not the same** as the order for [`mysql_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) (without the **`i`**).

Your code should look something like this:

```
/* $connect = mysqli_connect ( ... ); */

mysqli_select_db($connect, $database_connect);
$query_Users = "SELECT * FROM students";
$Users = mysqli_query($connect, $query_Users)
           or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$row_Users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Users);
$totalRows_Users = mysqli_num_rows($Users);
```

---

There's also a problem with this code:

> ```
> $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?  
>   mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);
> /* ... */
> ```

You're calling [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (without the **`i`**) instead of [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). The point of the "real" escape function is that the function takes the character encoding of the connection into account when escaping the string. However, you can't use a MySQLi link resource with the old MySQL escape function.

Since you're using MySQLi, there should be no need to check for the existence of the "real" escape function. Your code should read simply:

```
$theValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $theValue);
```

And make sure you connect to the database first.

---

Note that [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) and [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) may return `false`, and [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) may return `NULL`. Robust code should test (almost) all return values for error conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using mysql_ and mysql**i**_ functions. You should only use mysql**i** or PDO.
**mysql_ functions are already deprecated.**

mysqli_ functions are a bit different then mysql_ functions. Most time you need to add an extra parameter: the connection resource.

for example:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
mysqli_query($link, "SHOW TABLES");
```

Just google "**php** ***function-name***" to find information about specific functions

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Frankbeen but i have already done that in another file which I,m calling here just like I have done in any other file that forms part of the site.

Comment: I have also tried and changed to mysqli but the errors still persist